# How to find $P(A^{\textsf{c}} \cap B^{\textsf{c}})$ given $P(A), P(A \cup B)$ and $P(B^{\textsf{c}})$?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

How to find $P(A^{\textsf{c}} \cap B^{\textsf{c}})$ given $P(A), P(A \cup B)$ and $P(B^{\textsf{c}})$?

$A^{\textsf{c}}$ is the complement of $A$, and $B^{\textsf{c}}$ is the complement of $B$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It's been sometime since I did set theory questions. But I figured out it's De Morgan's Laws.
https://www.math24.net/set-identities/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $P$ is a probability measure, we can argue as follows: by de Morgan's Laws, $A^{\textsf{c}} \cap B^{\textsf{c}} = (A \cup B)^{\textsf{c}}$. Since $P$ is a function, $P(A^{\textsf{c}} \cap B^{\textsf{c}}) = P((A \cup B)^{\textsf{c}})$. We know that $P(A^{\textsf{c}}) = 1 - P(A)$. So
$$
P(A^{\textsf{c}} \cap B^{\textsf{c}}) = P((A \cup B)^{\textsf{c}}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)
$$
which gives the result.